# pandas dataframe: How to add subsequent rows of numerical data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with numbers only, and I would like to add subsequent rows. So from a dataframe like this:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  3
2  5  4
3  9  7
```

I would like to get a new dataframe like this:

```
    A   B
0   4   5
1   8   7
2  14  11
```

(The first row of the new dataframe contains the entries of the first two rows of the original dataframe, added up, etc.)

I have found the following way to do it:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,5,9], 'B': [2,3,4,7]})
new_rows = {}
for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):
    new_rows[i] = df.irow(i)+df.irow(i+1)
new_df = pandas.DataFrame(new_rows).transpose()
```

but it's neither fast nor very pretty. Any suggestions on how to optimise this, both for speed and python zen-ness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work and give you the same index as in your example

```
(df+df.shift(-1))[:-1]

Out[146]: 
    A   B
0   4   5
1   8   7
2  14  11
```

Comment: Thanks! Some timing results in case you are interested: my version took 1.39 s, yours 2.19 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas.DataFrame.add) on itself and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift), you then need to call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna):

```
In [228]:

df.add(df.shift()).dropna()
Out[228]:
    A   B
1   4   5
2   8   7
3  14  11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,5,9], 'B': [2,3,4,7]})

(df + df.shift(1)).dropna()


    A   B
1   4   5
2   8   7
3  14  11
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach with `head` and `tail`:

```
df.tail(-1).reset_index(drop=True) + df.head(-1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[41]:
    A   B
0   4   5
1   8   7
2  14  11
```